Why were these two flags declined?
I raised a "comment no longer needed" flag on the comment to this question: How is “戚” Being Used as a Standalone Verb to Mean “Feel”? [closed]

I will once the system lets me- there's apparently a two day waiting period

The comment is in response to a previous comment and refers to accepting the answer. Why would that comment be relevant today, especially considering that 1) the previous one "you can accept this" was in fact deleted, 2) the comment is dated 2017 and 3) the OP who could accept the answer hasn't logged in since 2017

The second one, still a "no longer needed" flag is the comment to this question Character difference between 'buy' and 'sell':

The two does not pronounce the same. 买(mǎi) and 卖(mài) are different.

The comment is not relevant anymore because the OP did edit their question after this comment, and now there's nothing in the question suggesting that the two characters have the same pronunciation.
Why were these two flags declined?

no explanation?
